# How to add Android x86 to Yumi!

Tags: usb, android, bootable

Is there any way to add android to Yumi? I want to be able to boot my computer from a USB stick and install android.

So, how can I  install Android using Yumi or any other multiboot USB creator?

Comment: Boot what? A computer? A phone?

Comment: I want to boot a computer using my usb and want to install android and ubuntu both in it!

Comment: And does your computer have an ARM CPU? If not, you'll need the Android port to x86. It would be far simpler to use a virtual machine.

Comment: @terdon Won't OP get better performance with Android x86 if he boots it directly, rather than a VM? Also, OP: Check out Remix OS. It's based on Android x86, but the GUI is redesigned for desktop.

Comment: @Fiksdal correct me if i'm wrong but aren't most of remixos's additions proprietary? Pretty crappy if you are looking for a pure (nexus-like) android experience.

Comment: @Wyatt8740 That's correct. OP didn't specify any need for open source or a nexus-like experience. The advantage of Remix OS is that they have made the interface adapted to a keyboard and mouse desktop setting and added some other optimizations that suit desktop users. While I do admire the FOSS philosophy, I don't at all mind using proprietary software either.

Comment: @Fiksdal okay. I'm fond of FOSS though and have gotten adept at using a physical mouse/keyboard on AOSP, but I think it should be noted that it's not 'free software' in the Stallman-sense. I try to avoid stuff like that because if I don't like something it does I have no way to change it (and I've grown to like my nexus). To each his own though.

Comment: @Wyatt8740 Sure, nothing wrong with pointing that out. Do you build custom roms for your Nexus? Or do you use Cyanogenmod? Do you use any proprietary apps? https://xkcd.com/225/

Comment: @Fiksdal I love that comic. I do have the Google API's on here, but don't think I've used any apps recently that use them. I have done a load of cross compiling and porting of 'traditional' unix tools to Android, though, and I use F-Droid for most things. I've not built a true 'custom rom', but when you've got ffmpeg & glibc & GNU coreutils & an X11 server & debian chroot on your rooted phone, the line starts to blur. I'm building a GCC toolchain _on_ android ATM. A few of my ports on my old website https://web.archive.org/web/20160530163333/http://wyatt8740.no-ip.org/android.html

Comment: @Wyatt8740 Yeah, chroot is really cool. I use it myself. And I have an x86 phone, so I can just get most of the software straight through `apt-get`. It's pretty neat how you can almost use the phone as a desktop computer.

Comment: Mine's armv7a, but since Debian packages most apps for armv7a, it's worked fine. Thinking of getting a BeagleBone X15 (cortex a15 based) SBC so I can have a proper arm-based desktop :D (though if one of the higher end MIPS cpu IPs ever gets manufactured for a SBC I'd like to try Mips android on that).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43604/discussion-between-fiksdal-and-wyatt8740).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download any ISO Image from the website http://www.android-x86.org. It's an Android distribution that works on normal x86 processors. For example, [Android 4.4](http://sourceforge.net/projects/android-x86/files/Release%204.4/android-x86-4.4-r4.iso/download). Then write that ISO to a flash drive.